# Error Could not find or load main class (java)

Tags: java, command

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Twk {

    public static void main(String[] Twk) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Twk");
        Scanner enterName = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = enterName.next();

    }

}
```

Why does it happen?
Twk.java and Twk.class are at the same place.
Need some helps, thanks.

Error: Could not find or load main class Twk
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlcUu.png

Comment: what's Twk.java looks like? does it have main method? what's package?

Comment: Have a look here for some hints on improving your question so you can get useful answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Why use `String[] Twk` ? Stick to java naming convention `String[] args`

Comment: Click [start](http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/871672) and see that the code runs, so the problem is elsewhere

Comment: This is mistake String[] args but not the problem that cannot run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work:

```
C:\Users\tsoiwingkui>cd desktop
C:\Users\tsoiwingkui\Desktop>javac Twk.java
C:\Users\tsoiwingkui\Desktop>java Twk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `java -cp . Twk`, this will probably let the java command "sees" the Twk.class file

Comment: @WingKuiTsoi have you declared the Twk class to be in a package? If so, use java package.name.Twk. Also does the Twk class contain the main method?

Comment: I don't have a package. I added my code to the question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure public class exists in the source file.
Twk java and Twk class is the same program.
Twk java is the source file and Twk class is executable file of the source code generated by jdk compiler.
Do this if not yet:

```
public class Twk{
 // your codes
 }
```

Comment: The result was the same: Error: Could not find or load main class Twk

Comment: Do you have a main method in the source file?
Please post your code here

Comment: The problem is in your main method, change it to:
public static void main(String[] args){ // your codes }

Comment: If your problem is solved please accept any one of the answers that best solve it.